# Disabling In on Spreader Click

Tags: wheelnav.js

I've tried to disable click on the 'Spreader' button. Cant seem to stop it from closing. I have an onmousedown event i want to keep but i don't want to close the spreader. Anyone know the best way to disable click on spreader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the minPercent property to achieve your needs.

```
var wheel;

window.onload = function () {
  wheel = new wheelnav("wheelDiv");
  wheel.spreaderEnable = true;
  wheel.createWheel(["This", "is", "custom", "spreader"]);
  wheel.spreadWheel();

  var wheelspreader = document.getElementById("wheelnav-wheelDiv-spreader");
  var wheelspreadertitle = document.getElementById("wheelnav-wheelDiv-spreadertitle");
  wheelspreader.onmousedown = function() {openSpreader();}
  wheelspreadertitle.onmousedown = function() {openSpreader();}
};

var openSpreader = function() {
  wheel.minPercent = wheel.maxPercent;
}
```

Here is a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/yudoxur/edit?html,js,output) for that.